# Get time from MySQL timestamp and show in hours, minutes etc?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to echo the `timestamp` in MySQL as seconds, minutes, days etc.

The script was working fine but I've had to tidy my code up a bit and now it won't get the time; it just echos out `0 days` or `0 hours` or `0 whatever`.

This is how it was before I touched the time code but I couldn't have it like this because I've had to edit some `div` orders.

So my question is please can someone tell me or show me what I've done for it to stop working? thank you

How it was before:

```
<div class="board-wall-feeds">        
<div class="social_header">
<?php echo "$profile[2]" ?>'s News & Updates:
</div>        
<?php
$timeline_set = get_timeline();
while ($news = mysql_fetch_array($timeline_set)) { 
echo "

<div class=\"news_feeds_board_text\">{$news['content']}
<div class=\"social_footer\"><a href=\"../../../delete_news_post.php?to=".$news['id']."</div><div class=\"social_clip\"></div></a>"; ?>


        <?
        $datetime1 = new DateTime();
        $datetime2 = new DateTime ($news['date_added']);
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        $mdhms = explode('-',$interval->format('%m-%d-%H-%i-%s'));

$labels = Array(' months', ' days', ' hours', ' minutes', ' seconds');
$i = 0;
foreach($mdhms as $t){
  if($t > 0) break;
  $i+=1;
}

        echo "about ".$t.$labels[$i]." ago"; ?></div></div>
        <? } ?>
```

How it is now with my new `div` order:

```
 <div class="board-wall-feeds">        
<div class="social_header">
<?php echo "$profile[2]" ?>'s News & Updates:
</div>        
<?php


        $datetime1 = new DateTime();
        $datetime2 = new DateTime ($news['date_added']);
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        $mdhms = explode('-',$interval->format('%m-%d-%H-%i-%s'));

$labels = Array(' months', ' days', ' hours', ' minutes', ' seconds');
$i = 0;
foreach($mdhms as $t){
  if($t > 0) break;
  $i+=1;
}



$timeline_set = get_timeline();
while ($news = mysql_fetch_array($timeline_set)) { 
echo "

<div class=\"news_feeds_board_text\">{$news['content']}
<div class=\"social_footer\">about ".$t.$labels[$i]." ago<a href=\"../../../delete_news_post.php?to=".$news['id']."</div><div class=\"social_clip\"></div></div></a>"; ?>


        <? } ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The below query will separate hour, minutes, seconds from the current time taken by NOW().

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H-%i-%S')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get those inside mysql query as below.

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(`time_stamp`, FORMAT) as ALIAS FROM 'table_name'
```

where `format` is in which format you want that date.

**For example** for get only `month` use it as  `STR_TO_DATE(time_stamp,'%m')` and so on.